# How can i log stdout and stderr outputs using fb-hydra?

Tags: python, python-logging, fb-hydra

I am trying to log stdout and stderr into a file.

I found custom.yaml file in the facebookresearch/hydra github.

```
# @package _group_
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '[%(levelname)s] - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
root:
  handlers: [console]

disable_existing_loggers: False
```

I figured that I am able to create a custom job_logging config file and log stderr by editing the file as below

```
stream: ext://sys.stderr
```

However, I want to log stderr and stdout at the same time.

I am having a hard time figuring it out.. Does anyone know how I can do it by changing the config file?

Comment: I just learned that adding a handler that handles stderr would do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydra is forwarding your config (as a primitive dictionary) to [logging.config.dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig).
This is more of question about that API than about Hydra.

Do you know how to do this via `logging.config.dictConfig` without Hydra?

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I am new to logging with python and wasn't aware that it is actually handled in logging module in python. I'll try to learn more about logging module. Thank you!

Comment: Reading your question more carefully:
You should also not edit the file inside Hydra. read the basic tutorial and the page on customizing logging (https://hydra.cc/docs/next/configure_hydra/logging).

Comment: @hyukyu, if this answers your question please accept the answer.